# How to implement Spring Boot search filter by date and order by result in createdadettime JSP, javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, jsp, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a spring boot web application. I am trying to implement a search filter in my application. I have a date field on my JSP page. So when I select any date from there, I should be able to get all records that lie on that particular date. So I have created a REST API to fetch records on a particular date. Below is my repository code:

```
    public interface OrdersDao extends JpaRepository<Orders, Long> {
        List<Orders> findByOrderdateOrderByCreateddatetimeDesc(Date date); // to fetch records in selected date
        List<Orders> findAllByStatus(int status, Pageable pageable); // to show active orders in table through pagination 
        List<Orders> findAllByStatus(int status); 
    }
```

This is my controller where I am handling response. The below code is to fetch orders on a selected date. For example, 6 orders have been placed on Date: 05-06-2021. So when I select this date, it should show me all those 6 orders ordered on that date.

```
@RequestMapping(value = AkApiUrl.searchbydate, method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<?> searchbydate(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("orderdate") String orderdate) {
        CustomResponse = ResponseFactory.getResponse(request);
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date allorderindate = sdf.parse(orderdate);
            List<Orders> orderlist = ordersdao.findByOrderdateOrderByCreateddatetimeDesc(allorderindate);
            if (orderlist != null) {
                CustomResponse.setResponse(orderlist);
                CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.OK);
                CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.OK_CODE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            CustomResponse.setResponse(null);
            CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);
            CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDao>(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

This is my script to handle the response in the front-end.

```
function searchorder(){
        var orderdate = document.getElementById('orderdate').value;
        var url = "../api/searchbydate";
        $.post(url,{
            orderdate : orderdate,
        },function(data, status) {
            if (data.status == "OK") {
                if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                        ordertable(<%=pagelength%>); // Here I called this function on ajax success, to display orders table on selected date.
                } else {
                    var error = data.responseMessage;
                    swal(error, "", "error");
                    }
            } else {
                var error = data.responseMessage;
                swal(error, "", "error");
                }
        });
    }
```

This is the function to create a dynamic table through AJAX, to handle heavy data load. This is done by pagination at the backend.

```
function ordertable(limit){
        var url = "../api/getallorder";
        $.post(url,{
            limit : limit,
            },function(data, status) {
                if (data.status == "OK") {
                    if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                        var row = "", page;
                        var orderlist = data.response;
                        var orderlistlength = orderlist.length;
                        var allorders = data.totalorders;
                        var count = allorders/10;
                        if(orderlistlength > 0){
                            for(var i = 0 ; i < orderlistlength ; i++){
                                row = row + "<tr><td>"+orderlist[i].orderid+"</td><td><a href=\"order-id.html\">"+orderlist[i].uniqueorderid+"</a></td>"
                                +"<td>"+orderlist[i].orderstatus+"</td><td>No records for time</td><td>No delivery type</td>"
                                +"<td>"+orderlist[i].userid.address+"</td><td>"+orderlist[i].totalamount+"</td><td>"+orderlist[i].userid.city+"</td>"
                                +"<td>No vendor's records yet</td></tr>";
                            }
                        }else{
                            row = "<tr><td colspan = 9>No Record Found.</td></tr>";
                        }
                        document.getElementById('orderspaginationdiv').innerHTML = row;
                    } else {
                        var error = data.responseMessage;
                        swal(error, "", "error");
                        }
                } else {
                    var error = data.responseMessage;
                    swal(error, "", "error");
                    }
                });
    }
```

So the thing is, I have tested searchbydate in postman, and I got desired result as a response. But I do not know where I am lacking from frontend. From interface when I am selecting date, it is fetching and displaying me all the data right from database. If any one have suggestions, then it would be appreciable. If anyone found any doubt, they can ask me.

[image: To depict whole scenario of problem]

Comment: print your ajax respons and check if the data is ordered or not.

Comment: Ajax response is printed in an ordered format.

Comment: can you please clarify what actually is causing the problem? I can see the data sorted in the image(all in same date though). Are you facing problem rendering it in HTML or the data you render is not sorted(though the image says the opposite)? I don't see any reason not to get sorted in your frontend!

Comment: I am getting data as expected from AJAX response. But the thing is, when I am selecting any other date from date field, then also, It is displaying the whole data from database on table. I hope, now you understand.